# Is it possible to find a circle with exactly 5 rational points?

Tags: geometry, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, arithmetic-geometry

Can we find a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with exactly 5 points with rational coordinates?

What is obvious is that a circle with a rational center and a rational radius has infinitely many rational points. And that a circle with a radius whose square is irrational and a rational center has no rational points.

I tried finding a circle with 1 rational point but to no avail.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you, for example, prove that the center must be rational?

Comment: *"What is obvious is [...] that a circle with an irrational radius and a rational center has no rational points."* ... Um ... $x^2+y^2=2$?

Comment: What are the rational points you imply?

Comment: Hint: If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ are rational points on the circle, then all $(\pm x, \pm y)$ are rational and on the same circle. So, you cannot have odd number of rational points.

Comment: @Bumblebee Are you assuming that the circle must be centered at the origin (or at least a rational point)?

Comment: The center is not necessarily (0,0).

Comment: @CalvinLin: I see, thanks for the correction. But my assertion can be modified to any circle with a rationally coordinated center.

Comment: @Blue: I meant that the square of the radius. I've corrected my question.

Comment: @Bumblebee Yes, that's why I pointed out you made that assumption of a rational center / origin. (Note that if the circle isn't centered at the origin, then $(\pm x \pm y ) $ need not be on the circle However, $ (r_x \pm x, r_y \pm y) $ is ). $ \quad$ However, you've not dealt with the case of a non-rational center, so I'm not certain that you truly have a hint that can be completed into a solution based on your intentions. If you were merely making an observation, then don't use the loaded term "hint".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim: If the circle has (at least) 3 rational points, then

1. the center is rational (so we can translate to the origin), and
2. the set of rational points is infinite, actually dense.

So the answer is no.

If you're stuck proving these statements, show what you've tried.

> 1) (If you don't have a slick argument,) You can find the coordinates of the center by taking the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors.

> 2) From a rational point on the circle, take a line with rational slope. Show that it intersects the circle again at a rational point.

---

Notes:

- I know of a circle with exactly 0 rational points.
- I know of a circle with exactly 2 rational points -> This is similar to (arguably identical to) 2009 Putnam B1, which is why the above approach was so familiar to me.
- Lulu provided an example of a circle with exactly 1 rational points in the comments.

Comment: To make an example with  exactly $2$ rational points:  Let $P,Q$ be your two (distinct) rational points and let $C$ be an irrational point on the perpendicular bisector of $P,Q$.  Taking $C$ as the center, gives you an example.   And, for exactly $1$, use $x^2+(\pi-y)^2=\pi^2$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for that example :)

Comment: I proved the first point. Which means proving the property for a circle centered at the origin is sufficent.   By simply considering $(x,y)$ and $(-x,y)$ etc... one can prove that the number of solutions is even. But how can I prove that it's infinite?

Comment: @AymaneMaaitat Hint: From a rational point on the circle, take a line with rational slope. Show that it intersects the circle again at a rational point.